# ModuleNotFoundError when I run django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

when I want to runserver my django project I get below Error:

```sh
(belov_wed_venv) prateek@prateek:~/belov_wed/project_belov_wed$ python manage.py runserver

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ' belov_wed_app'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Share your project structure, please

Comment: Also, please add the whole stack trace and your `settings.py`. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough. On the first look it might be that you have an unnecessary space in INSTALLED_APPS for your app in the beginning.

Comment: where you use `belov_wed_app` or import it?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because I didn't do apt setting in the app and my main projects `urls.py`, also I forgot to reconfigure my`INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` module.

Thank you all. I resolved it. The error is not displayed properly because Stack Overflow was not allowing me to add the error.